# how many times will the student take the exam before passing it

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

If the probability of a stuent passing an exam is p = 53/130 how many times will the student take the exam before passing the exam?

I think that this is geometric distribution.
so E(x) = 1/p = 1/(53/130) = 2.45 so the student will fail the exam on the 1st and the 2nd try and will pass the exam on the 3rd try.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Well, the expected value is what you say, but of course that does not mean that the student *will* "fail the exam on the first and the second try and will pass on the third".  Expectation is not certainty.

Comment: So, my question is after getting E(x) = 2.45 , can we say that we expect the student to fail the exam 2 times and pass it on the 3rd try? I was wondering about the rounding - is it 2 fails and passing on the 3rd try or 3 times failing and passing on the 4th try

Comment: Expected value just means that, if you ran this experiment lots and lots of times, then you expect the average number of times to be $2.45$